# How to diplay two <span> inline?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input  mr-3">
  <input type="text" name="title" class="input100 text1" autocomplete="off" required>

  <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Title"></span>
  <span class="count1 text-secondary"></span>

</div>
```

I need to display both `span` inline. `display-inline: flex;` seems not work.

I have a `CSS` that i downloaded from a website, to stylize my input, the `CSS` is really big, so i cant put here on the snipped.

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/user236945896/pen/yRBLPM

Comment: and why a *really big* CSS for a tiny HTML?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Actually this `CSS` is not only for this input, its for a layout, to a login system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you want because your question isn't really clear.

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input  mr-3">
  <input type="text" name="title" style="display:inline-block;width:auto;" class="input100 text1" autocomplete="off" required>

    <span class="focus-input100" style="width:auto" data-placeholder="Title"></span>
    <span class="count1 text-secondary"></span>

</div>
```

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NOKWmb

Answer (score 0):

You already tried some like these? Run this code and see if it helps you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
span.a {
    display: inline; /* the default for span */
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;    
    background-color: yellow; 
}

span.b {
    display: inline-block;    
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;        
    background-color: yellow; 
}

span.c {
    display: block;    
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;        
    background-color: yellow; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The display Property</h1>

<h2>display: inline</h2>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat scelerisque elit sit amet consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. <span class="a">Aliquam</span> <span class="a">venenatis</span> gravida nisl sit amet facilisis. Nullam cursus fermentum velit sed laoreet. </div>

<h2>display: inline-block</h2>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat scelerisque elit sit amet consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. <span class="b">Aliquam</span> <span class="b">venenatis</span> gravida nisl sit amet facilisis. Nullam cursus fermentum velit sed laoreet. </div>

<h2>display: block</h2>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum consequat scelerisque elit sit amet consequat. Aliquam erat volutpat. <span class="c">Aliquam</span> <span class="c">venenatis</span> gravida nisl sit amet facilisis. Nullam cursus fermentum velit sed laoreet. </div>

</body>
</html>
```